# How can I iterate over multidimensional python dictionaries without having to detect if they have sub lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have the following dictionary:

```
a = { 'string1':'string2', 
      'nested': ['string3', 'string4'] }
```

And I'm interested in iterating through all possible values regardless of whether they are in a list or not (string2, string3, string4)

```
for b in a.itervalues()
```

would get me all the keys, but they would look like:

```
['string3', 'string4']
string2
```

I could then check for:

```
isinstance(values, list)
```

and add a second for-loop, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Your method is the most elegant way to do it. Remember the Zen of Python.

Comment: A good example of why mixing types as values is not always a good idea

Comment: Yeah, I think in the long term mixing types is just not worth it. I may just switch everything to a list for consistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> b = []
>>> for item in a.values():
...     b.extend(item) if isinstance(item,list) else b.append(item)
... 
>>> b
['string2', 'string3', 'string4']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `isinstance` and `if/else` but if you you want a one liner:

```
a = { 'string1': 'string2',
  'nested': ['string3', 'string4']}

from itertools import chain

for v in chain(*(v if isinstance(v, list) else (v,)
             for v in a.itervalues())):
    print(v)
```

If you want the data stored:

```
from itertools import chain

vals = list(chain(*(v if isinstance(v, list) else (v,)
                 for v in a.itervalues())))
print(vals)

['string3', 'string4', 'string2']
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want a flat list of values:

```
li = []

for k in a.keys():
    val = a[k]
    if type(val) == list:
        li.extend(val)
    else:
        li.append(val)
```

print(li)

**output**

['string3', 'string4', 'string2']